# How much does the bus over the Thai Lao friendship bridge cost from the Laos side?

Tags: borders, transportation, thailand, fees-and-charges, laos

I've got a week left on my Laos visa but I'd have to visit the ATM again and the fees are really high these days. So I'm thinking of heading back to Thailand. But want to make sure I keep enough `LAK` for the compulsory bus ride over Friendship Bridge #1.

A few weeks back I came in the other direction and [the price for the bus on the Thai side was only in Baht: 35 `THB` + 5 more overtime fee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/20321/140) if you're too early in the morning or too late in the evening.

I can't seem to find a reliable source for the ride from Laos to Thailand though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I crossed the border back from Vientiane to Nong Khai 2 days ago, January 15, 2024.

Price is currently **₭15,000 Lao Kip** or **฿30 Thai Baht**.

Note that that's about 10 baht / 2,500 kip cheaper in Lao Kip if you happen to have a choice of currencies with you.

As a bonus I can also tell you that the bus over Friendship Bridge #1 runs from 6.00 AM to 9.30 PM.

[image: Lao bus ticket]

[image: price sign on Lao side]

[image: ticket window on Lao side]

Answer (score 4):

When I was in Laos, I had to make that same trip (around June/July 2023). The bus ride from Laos to Thailand over Friendship Bridge #1 should cost you around 20,000 LAK. Keep some LAK handy for that. As for the bus fare on the Thai side, it's still 35 THB, but watch out for that additional 5 THB if you're too early or too late.